# parsing a label value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Given this markup

```
<asp:Label id="lblMonthlyDataCost" CssClass="labelValueCalc" Text="29,000"
               runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

which is formatted on page load using

```
 lblMonthlyDataCost.Text = FormatCurrency(Convert.ToDecimal(lblMonthlyDataCost.Text),        2).ToString()
```

I cannot parse the value from that label in jquery as it always returns 29 instead of 29,000
ce this is a dollar amount but I thought that may have been the issue since there was no decimal

```
var injCost = parseInt($("#lblInjectorCost").text().replace("$",""));
```

Comment: Do you get 29,000 in the rendered HTML? May be its a Convert problem, if you are running with an incorrect culture, it may treat as the comma a decimal point, and just return 39.

Comment: For the first round of analyzing your problem the server side code is not that important. Can you post the generated HTML code, please?

Comment: That's exactly what `parseInt` does, it takes a float/number/string and parses it as an integer removing everything after the decimal point, both `,` and `.` as it's only zeros, and the closest number would be 29

Comment: Also, I guess the id mismatch is a mistake when posting the question? lblMonthlyDataCost  vs #lblInjectorCost?

Comment: yes, the label renders correctly as $29,000 but I cannot parse its value to use as a formula in jquery

Comment: adeneo ....well how do I parse it to get the correct value? 29,000

Comment: Did you try the answer below? Just add a radix as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var injCost = parseInt($("#lblInjectorCost").text().replace(/\D/g,""));
```